# HP Office Jet 8600 scanner support

Tags: hp, scanner

I recently upgraded an older Windows 7 computer to Ubuntu 14.04, and added a new HP OfficeJet 8600 all-in-one printer.  The printer works fine, but the scanner is not recognized.  Running HP-CHECK states that I am missing packages for PYTHON-SDK, and others, required for "scanner" to work.  Can you help?  I can scan using another computer, and USB stick transfer, but would prefer direct scanning.

Additional Information:

command `sudo hp-check -r` resulted in multiple pages of log

Initial display is probably the underlying cause:

```
warning: ubuntu-14.04 version is not supported.
```

Using ubuntu-13.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

The summary of errors indicates that there are some missing libraries:

Missing Required Dependencies

```
error: 'libdbus-1-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'openssl' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-client' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible
```

Missing Optional Dependencies

```
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible
```

Comment: Can you include the errors that you receive by editing and including them in your question? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo hp-setup -i` Also are you using simple scan? Or some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to upgrade HPLIP to version 3.14.4

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html had all required instructions.

Note the USB port on printer accepted scan, and I could see the memory stick on the main computer (through the printer's USB port.
I cannot yet get the scanner to go directly to the computer, but using a memory stick in the USB port is sufficient for me.